# Fish shell creating functions using eval'd output from another exe

Tags: fish

On Ubuntu Server 16.10 x64 with fish 2.3.1, my `uru_rt` exe generates this function on stdout

```
function uru
  set -x URU_INVOKER fish

  # uru_rt must already be on PATH
  uru_rt $argv

  if test -d "$URU_HOME" -a -f "$URU_HOME/uru_lackee.fish"
    source "$URU_HOME/uru_lackee.fish"
  else if test -f "$HOME/.uru/uru_lackee.fish"
    source "$HOME/.uru/uru_lackee.fish"
  end
end
```

when run via `uru_rt admin install`. The `uru` function provides the golang-based cross-platform ruby version manager tool https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru

On bash systems, I inject the `uru` function by placing `eval "$(uru_rt admin install)"` in a startup file so that `uru` is present in the shell.

On fish, running `eval (uru_rt admin install)` rewards me with this failure

```
$ eval (uru_rt admin install)
Missing end to balance this begin
- (line 1): begin; function uru   set -x URU_INVOKER fish    # uru_rt must already be on PATH   uru_rt $argv    if test -d "$URU_HOME" -a -f "$URU_HOME/uru_lackee.fish"     source "$URU_HOME/uru_lackee.fish"   else if test -f "$HOME/.uru/uru_lackee.fish"     source "$HOME/.uru/uru_lackee.fish"   end end
            ^
from sourcing file -
    called on line 60 of file /usr/share/fish/functions/eval.fish

in function “eval”
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file “-”
```

I've also tried `set u1 (uru_rt admin install); eval "$u1"` with the same result.

As expected, when I do `uru_rt admin install > ~/.config/fish/functions/uru.fish` the `uru` function becomes persistently available. While this is an option, my preference is to use `eval` in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

As a noob to fish, how do I dynamically inject this `uru` function into the environment using `eval` similar to bash's `eval "$(uru_rt admin install)"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish's `eval` is a wrapper function around its `source` builtin, and it seems there's some weirdness (maybe even a bug) going on with it's argument splitting when you pass multiple lines..

However, in this case it's simpler, faster and actually working if you just use `source`, like `uru_rt admin install | source`.

That assumes though that `uru_rt admin install` really needs to be called - if all it does is print that code to stdout, without changing it, you can also simply save the function, e.g. in ~/.config/fish/functions/uru.fish.

Comment: Your `uru_rt admin install | source` works perfectly from `~./config/fish/config.fish` as a non-persistent alternative to `~/.config/fish/functions/uru.fish`